# Error when installing microsoft visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I install Visual Studio 2013, I receive this error.  How can I fix this?

[[image]

Comment: What does that log file contain?

Comment: The error you *should* be seeing is `E3141: Why the heck are you using such an outdated product?` :-)

Comment: Unless you have a very strong justification, VS2013 Community Edition is no longer a valid product you should try. Itself is supported till 2024 by Microsoft, but many of the technologies included inside are out of support already. Use VS2019 Community Edition and that's far better.